# Two websites in different servers has same cookie_domain but is not sharing session

Tags: session, memcache, cookie

I have two different sites that has their own server. Site#2 sends request to Site#1 for logging customer in. Request contains Allow Crendentials Header and response is status 200. Both sites has same memcache COOKIE_DOMAIN but for some reason Site#2 has no set $_SESSION values. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually share the session data between the web servers. The cookie is merely an index to the session storage.

How exactly you can make the web servers share session data depends entirely on the software stack used on the servers.

Comment: Site #2 is running on centOs and has php 5.3.21 and apache 2.2.22 while Site #1 is running on ubuntu 14.04.5 and has php 5.6.30 and apache 2.4.25. How can I configure them to actually share the sessions? They are both running on Virtual Box on my local

Comment: You need to find out the application that actually creates the sessions and see how you can share the sessions it creates. If it hasn't been designed for it, you cannot share sessions.

Comment: Problem is fixed now. I just allowed my memcache port on iptables in Site#1 so that Site#2 can access it